# CharSequence to represent a named object

Tags: java, class-design, class, strings, conventions

I always followed the opinion to not abuse interfaces in case of decomposition.
Usually I only implement them if I am absolutely sure to have a "is-a"-relation and avoid implementing them if there is a "has-a"-relation to another kind of object.

Now, this ethic leads me to a problem:
I'm writing a small library including a type containing a "name" property.
The objects representing this type are almost exclusively created through a XML-file where they are defined.
The idea behind giving those objects a name is to easily access them in the code.

The definition looks like this:

```
<root>
    <object name="foo">
    ....
    </object>
</root>
```

In the code it should be possible to apply any representor of this type by name or by the object itself. So the type includes a name:

```
public interface NamedObject {

    String getName();

    .....
}
```

So now the following two samples should create the same result:

Sample 1:

```
NamedObject obj = Utils.getFromXML("obj_name");
Foo.doStuff(obj);
```

Sample 2:

```
Foo.doStuff("obj_name");
```

The reason why this should work is that there may be a context where the programmer is already working with such a named object and so he should be able to use it directly like in Sample 1.
But there may be a context where he wants to call a method depending on such an object and the programmer might want to use a named object he defined in the XML. Then he could just lookup the name and use it via its name.

The actual problem is, that this is leading me to a mess in my structural design as there are a lot of objects requiring those kind of objects in their methods and in most cases there is a default behavoir defined as well.

So if there is a default behavior I need 3 implementations of the method.

```
public interface Bar {

    void doStuff()

    void doStuff(String namedObjectName);

    void doStuff(NamedObject object);
}
```

So 6 functionalities for example would lead to 18 methods.

I think there might be no other way to represent the default behavoir than providing a method without parameter. I could run the default behavoir by accepting null pointers and run the default behavoir if a null pointer is given but in my eyes, a param-less method is the prettier solution.

So to get rid of one of the other two signatures the `NamedObject`-type could inherit from `java.lang.CharSequence`.
The implementations of the methods of `java.lang.CharSequence` could be done by using the name property.
Since Java 8 I could already default implement them in the interface using the `getName()` method.

With this move I could replace the method accepting the `java.lang.String` parameter representing the name and the method accepting the `NamedObject` with a single method accepting a `java.lang.CharSequence` representing either the name or the object itself.

The `NamedObject`-type itself CLEARLY DOES NOT represent a "is-a" relation to its name. It represents a "has-a" relation.

And that's the question. What's the best way to design a library including such a structure? Is my new intention ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheriting from `java.lang.CharSequence` will probably cause you much more maintenance headaches in the future, not just because of the has-a/is-a design glitch.

I think the real problem is that you are trying to support calls like this directly:

```
  Foo.doStuff("obj_name");
```

That way, your `Foo` class needs to be coupled to `Utils.getFromXML`, which makes it probably more complex than it needs to be. Lets ignore the "default behaviour" part of your question for a moment. So I recommend to design your interface just like this:

```
public interface Bar {
    void doStuff(NamedObject object);
}
```

and if you need this, provide a helper or utility class `XmlUtil` containing a function like this

```
public void DoStuff(Bar bar, String objname)
{
    NamedObject obj = Utils.getFromXML(objname);
    bar.DoStuff(obj);
}
```

So you can call it like

```
XmlUtil.DoStuff(Foo, "obj-name");
```

which is only a little bit longer than your original call, but makes the Xml context explicit.

That way, you do not have to provide the same "string -> object" mapping in each `Bar` implementation over and over again, you can reuse the function above for any `Bar` implementation. Moreover, only your utility class now needs to be coupled to the Xml directly, not your `Bar implementations.

Comment: Thank you! I think i will either do it your way or by default imlpementing the extra methods in interface as [Java 8 provides this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)